# Navbar doubles in height on resizing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've (almost) created a responsive navbar however between phone screen size and full window size the bar doubles in height. I've tried a bunch of bootstrap classes without success. This is the full screen format (correct):

[image]

And this is after reducing the browser window size (incorrect):

[image]

If anyone could tell me what is causing this it would be really helpful.

```html
    <!-- header area start -->
    <header id="header">
    <div class="header-area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <!-- <div class="menu-area"> -->
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="logo px-4">
                            <h3 style="color: #ffffff;"><a style="color: #ffffff;">Header</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9 d-none d-md-block">
                        <div class="main-menu">
...
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-12 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none d-block d-sm-none">
                        <div class="mobile_menu"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <!-- header area end -->
```

```css
.header-area{position:fixed;left:0;top:0;width:100%;z-index:998;background-color:#27ae60}
.menu-area{display:flex;align-items:center}
.logo h3{font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;color:#fff}
.logo a{display:inline-block;font-family:'Lato',sans-serif;color:#fff;font-size:18px}
```

Comment: If you remove all of the extra code from that html, you might have better luck. Not only in getting an answer, but in figuring out what's happening. Ideally, you want to narrow it down to just the divs causing the problem. I.e., remove all of the {% %} so that this becomes strictly an HTML/CSS problem. If that makes it work, then you know it's something in your template code, etc.

Comment: I would guess that when it gets to medium size it is stacking the divs through bootstrap and the col-md-12 class. Use the inspector to find out what the large area above the links is related to.

Comment: @ThomasByy I completely forgot about the inspector tool, thank you. Turns out it was the col-lg-9 class inside the row class. Feel free to expand on this so I can give you the answer as I still don't understand why the col classes would be stacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I know every immediate child of the `row` class should typically be a `col` so that all children equals 12 and assigns the width accordingly. When you say `col-lg-9` that means that while we are in a large viewport this div should take up 9/12 width. When it is a viewport below large (`lg`) we will be the full 12 wide and start to stack. So for example

large

`| col-lg-2 |          col-lg-6          |    col-lg-4    |`

medium and small

`|     col-lg-2     |
 |     col-lg-6     |
 |     col-lg-4     |`

you can fine tune this with md and sm and customise what happens when it reaches those viewports. I don't think it's a great explanation but I hope it helped. You should try to keep your classes equalling 12 and using the same size `lg` or `md` or `sm` across all of them.

Comment: So you would want to use `sm` classes so even in a small viewport you can control the widths and not have it stack.